# JPA Query incorrectly uses parenthesis which results in a different query

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, plsql, eclipselink

I need to retrieve all the T1 objects from a table based on a condition where the expire date is null and the query should retrieve only T16_ID of three types which are A, B and C. I have the below simple SQL query for this which returns the correct result.
    SELECT * FROM T1 d 
    WHERE d.T1_T2_ID_FK = '123' 
    AND d.T1_DATE_EXPIRED IS NULL 
    AND (d.T16_ID LIKE 'A' OR
    d.T16_ID LIKE 'B'
    OR d.T16_ID LIKE 'C');

I use JPA for object relational mapping in my application and below is my respective JPA query

```
TypedQuery<T1Docs> query = em.createQuery(
        "**SELECT t FROM T1Docs t WHERE t.t1ID.t2Id = :idNum 
        AND t.t1DateExpired IS NULL 
        AND (t.t16DocType.t16Id LIKE :docType1 OR t.t16DocType.t16Id LIKE :docType2 OR t.t16DocType.t16Id LIKE :docType3**)",T1Docs.class);

query.setParameter("idNum", idNumber);
query.setParameter("docType1", "%" + "A" + "%");
query.setParameter("docType2", "%" + "B" + "%");
query.setParameter("docType3", "%" + "C" + "%");
```

above query doesnt return any result and when I debug the plogram I found that the query is generated as below.

```
SELECT t0.T1_ID, t0.T1_DATE_CAPTURED, t0.T1_DATE_EXPIRED, t0.T1_T16_ID_FK 
FROM T1_OWNER_DOCUMENT t0, T16_DOC_TYPE t1 WHERE ((((t0.T1_T2_ID_FK = ?) 
AND (t0.T1_DATE_EXPIRED IS NULL)) 
AND ((t1.T16_ID LIKE ? OR t1.T16_ID LIKE ?) 
OR t1.T16_ID LIKE ?)) AND (t1.T16_ID = t0.T1_T16_ID_FK))
```

because of the incorrect usage of parenthesis, the generated query becomes incorrect and It doesn't return any result.

If anyone knows how to fix this issue in the JPA query because I am new to JPA and having trouble in understanding how to use OR with multiple checks along with AND and parenthesis.

Comment: It isn't clear that your SQL is the same as what you want from the JPQL as you aren't showing an inner join required for the t.t16DocType.t16Id relationship. From Looking at the SQL generated from the JPQL, I see no problems with it - to my eye it has the like clauses in their own block "((t1.T16_ID LIKE ? OR t1.T16_ID LIKE ?) OR t1.T16_ID LIKE ?)" which is equivalent to the SQL you provided.  The only difference I see is your inner join, so it means your data doesn't match the mappings, as some of the T1Docs with foreign key values don't line up with T16_DOC_TYPE rows

Comment: T1 table has two foreign keys which are T1_T2_ID_FK which  maps with T2 table and T1_T16_ID_FK which maps with T16 table. In the JPQL I’m passing both of them as parameters and since the entities map them automatically through the jpa entities I haven’t added the inner join in the jpql. In my sql queries as an example I have added a value for them which is the difference.

Comment: As mentioned, the only way this inner join is a problem is if the foreign key has a value in it that matches those OR conditions, but does not have a corresponding row in the joined table. This would break any foreign key constraint, so this is not a proper foreign key relationship.  For example, what does the relationship show when you read in the T1Docs instance(s) that match your SQL query, using something like the primary key? The t.t16DocType relationship cannot possibly reflect the database, as there won't be a t16DocType instance to build.

Comment: If you want to be able to access the T1_OWNER_DOCUMENT.T1_T16_ID_FK without a join on it, you should look at mapping it with a basic mapping.  You can still use it in a relationship mapping, you will just need to decide which mapping should control it and mark the other(s) as insertable=false, updatable=false. When ever you don't want to use a join or access the value directly, use the basic mapping in your JPA queries.

Comment: Correct. I haven't done the mapping of T1ID properly and that was the cause of this issue.